# url.isFileReferenceURL() returns false for local file in IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I opened a PNG file in my app from another application.

It invokes `application(application: UIApplication, handleOpenURL url: NSURL) -> Bool` this function.

The following is what I did to test if the coming file is valid:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleOpenURL url: NSURL) -> Bool {
    var rootViewController : ViewController = self.window?.rootViewController as ViewController
    println("the received url is \(url) and \(url.isFileReferenceURL())")
    if url.isFileReferenceURL() {
        rootViewController.handleOpenURL(url)
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

But when debugging, url.isFileReferenceURL() returns false for a example file link like the following:

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Applications/56-random-identifier/Documents/Inbox/whatever.png
```

What is happening here? Why is the function return false for a local file? Thank you!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have misunderstood what `-isFileReferenceURL` is about. I'm guessing you're interested in whether the URL is a file URL; that is, whether it refers to a local file rather than a remote resource. For that, you should call `-isFileURL` or, equivalently, check the `fileURL` property (e.g. `url.fileURL`).

File URLs come in two flavors. There are file path URLs and file reference URLs. File path URLs are based on the path, as you would expect. If the referenced file is moved, the URL will not track it to its new location. If a different file is created at the path, the URL will then refer to that new file.

A file reference URL refers to the underlying file object in the file system, independent of the path. If the file is moved *within the same volume* or renamed, the URL will track the file. It will continue to reference it even though its path has changed.

You can convert back and forth between the two flavors using `-filePathURL` and `-fileReferenceURL`. You can determine the flavor using `-isFileReferenceURL`.

When you create a file URL using any of the `WithPath:` methods, you get a file path URL. That's why you're seeing `-isFileReferenceURL` return false.

Comment: No. A bookmark persists across application runs and even reboots. It can also potentially track a file that has moved across volumes. (Also, a bookmark may prefer a new file at the old path even if the old file still exists but has been moved.)

Comment: well explained! Thank you

Comment: @KenThomases Just to complete my understanding -- is it true that a file reference is mapped to an inode?

Comment: @noamtm, that's an implementation detail that Apple hasn't documented. So, you should not rely on it either way. More the point, I don't know if it is or not and I don't feel that has left a hole in my understanding.